# Mpeg 7 Descriptors in C++

Tags: c++, c, mpeg

I need some descriptors of MPEG7 in C/C++. The descriptors are dominant color, color layout, color structure, scalable color, edge histogram and homogeneous texture. Do you know where can I find C/C++ source code for some of these these descriptors?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the MPEG-7 feature extraction library and source code with OpenCV (2.2) at http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~bilmdg/bilvideo-7/Software.html

Answer (score 0):

You should get the reference software that comes with the standard from [here](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/). Read more about the reference software [here](http://www.chiariglione.org/mpeg/technologies/mp07-rsw/index.htm).

A <strike>commercial</strike> LGPL (since version 2.3) library can be found [here](http://www.clinicip.org/index.php?id=80).

Comment: The Mpeg7 library (from Joanneum Research) does not include Feature Extractors